# Expo Project warn No apps connected

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I am trying to run my react native expo project on my android phone (also iOS), but have been running into some problems. Everytime I try to open the dev menu on the app running on the device, I get the warning

```
warn No apps connected. Sending "devMenu" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.
```

This also happens when I try to reload it through the cli. The app is running fine as it builds and is able to make requests to my API, but these features are not working, and the hot reload that happened when I saved a file in my project also gives me the error:

```
Could not reload the application after an edit.
```

This started happening last week, and after the expo SDK 45 was released (though I'm not sure if it was immediately after that), and I have tried upgrading my packages, reinstalling expo cli, deleting my project folder and cloning it again, running on android and iOS, and also running the adb reverse tcp command, unfortunately to no avail.

Has anyone been through this kind of problem with an expo project? Have any solutions been found? And is it related to the new SDK update?

Thank you for the help in advance

Comment: seeing this with expo 44 too

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost positive it's a bug with Expo 45 - been running into this since upgrading to it.

Answer (score 0):

Update the expo cli to the latest version eg:

```bash
npm install -g expo-cli
```

Fixes the issue for reload on SDK 45.